# Angular injected service is not singltone

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I created a new angular project with two components, app component and TempComponent, and a service called TempService.

I wish to inject this service to both components as a singleton. The components and the service are all in the same module and I register the service in the module's "providers" array. However each time the component is created the service's ctor is called as well(and not once as I expected and rad online). I can't find the problem.

The service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TempService{
    constructor(){
        console.log("TEmp Service was created");
    }
}
```

The components:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private tmp:TempService){}
}

export class TempComponent{
    constructor(private tmp:TempService){}
}
```

The module:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'temp', component: TempComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TempComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: false } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  providers: [TempService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like you also added `TempService` to `providers: [...]` of the component. You should **only** add it to providers in `@NgModule()`. Also adding a service to providers of lazy loaded modules can result in additional instances being created.

Comment: Nope, just to the mosule's providers array

Comment: There there has to be some other fishy thing. Can you reproduce in Plunker or https://stackblitz.com?

Comment: I think it has to do with the routing... when I use TempComponent inside AppComponent it works well.

Comment: I can't imagine. I haven't seen anything like this happening since `NgModule` was introduced. I think this really needs a reproduction to investigate.

Comment: Is there a hierarchy of your components, try to declare service in `AppComponent`, and use `TempComponent` inside `AppComponent` for example.

Comment: In that case it will work but that's not the scenario I'm looking for(which is authorization service that is accessed all across the app)